# No such Module after successful building yesterday

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Why out of no where am I getting that certain modules are not found?

[image]

Here is my pod file

```
 platform :ios, '9.0'
project '.xcodeproj location'

target 'SoldFor' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SoldFor
pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'MaterialComponents'
pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 5.0.1'
# pod 'Charts'
pod 'MaterialComponents/ActivityIndicator'
pod 'MaterialComponents/Chips'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
 pod 'SDWebImage', :modular_headers => true
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
end
```

Yesterday everything was fine, then out of no where, this happens.

Things I have done:

- I cleaned the project
- I restarted the project
- I deleted the workspace and redid a `pod install`
- I 'almost' threw my laptop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: If I do a head and remove that import, and the code that goes with it... I then try to rebuild, then the project complains about import Firebase saying there is no such module.

Comment: Build the project to reset the Xcode module cache

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I did that too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone finds this, and really for me to go back to it incase this happened again.

Open but the Build Settings for your application.

- Look for `Framework Search Paths`
- Double click on debug
- If there is anything in that list, highlight it all and click on the - button to remove it.
- Click the + sign, and add the following: `$(inherited)` (make sure its non-recursive)
- **Do the same for Release**

**Do the same for** `Header Search Paths`